# Phpmyadmin cant seem to read config

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, configuration

I'm in the process of setting up a LEMP (Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP) server with phpMyAdmin.

I installed and followed the various instructions including the create_tables script they provide etc (I've verified the pma user exists, as well as the tables).

However, when I login to phpMyAdmin I get these 2 errors:

- The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.
- The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).

Additionally, the blowfish secret is set in the config file so this leads me to believe that PMA cant read the config file - but i'm not sure what to do!

Have tried fiddling permissions and owners but no help - although was very much guessing as to which chmod/chown it should be!

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you copy + rename the config file, or are you editing the original?

Comment: First I tried using the wizard but it asks for a directory called config, which even though I created and chmod 777 it still couldn't see it. So copied the sample config to config.inc.php but nothing still.

Comment: What folders are your phpmyadmin installation and config file respectively?...   This post in a relevant thread may be relevant: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1227734&s=ca7062b2e1a1e4b3c17e52b824c3222d&p=7786117#post7786117

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy + rename the config file, or are you editing the original?

Your config file may also be in the wrong location.

This post in a relevant thread may be relevant:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1227734&s=ca7062b2e1a1e4b3c17e52b824c3222d&p=7786117#post7786117